# R count values in column where another column is unique

Tags: r

I have a data frame 'df' like

```
      user_id     value
1      t34        A
2      t34        A
3      t87        A
4      t55        B
5      t55        B
6      t76        B
7      t99        A
```

if i do

```
table(df$value)
```

I get

```
 A    B
 4    3
```

but I only want to count once per user, something like

```
table(df$value WHERE user_id IS unique)
```

and get

```
 A    B
 3    2
```

How can this be done?

Comment: A `dplyr` solution would be `df %>% group_by(value) %>% summarize(n_distinct(user_id))`.

Comment: @jake this gives the error Error in resolve_vars(new_groups, tbl_vars(.data)) : 
  unknown variable to group by : value

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that error.  Here's what I'm running.  `library(dplyr) ; df <- data.frame(user_id = c("t34", "t34", "t87", "t55", "t55", "t76", "t99"), value = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A")) ; df %>% group_by(value) %>% summarize(n_distinct(user_id))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take the unique rows first, then tabulate.

```
table(unique(df)$value)
#
# A B 
# 3 2
```

If you have other columns, then you can take a column subset first, then tabulate.

```
with(unique(df[c("user_id", "value")]), table(value))
# value
# A B 
# 3 2
```

Comment: I have a lot of other columns so it returns < table of extent 0 >, if i do table(unique(df$user_id)$value) it returns Error in unique(df$user_id)$value : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @RunnerBean - Okay, then try `with(unique(df[c("user_id", "value")]), table(value))`.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df))[, .N, value]
#   value N
#1:     A 3
#2:     B 2
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df) %>% 
           count(value)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
#  value     n
#   <chr> <int>
#1     A     3
#2     B     2
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution submitted are all perfect. Here I would like to provide an approach using the `duplicated` function in base R. `duplicated` function can determine which rows are duplicates of other rows in a data frame. It can take a data frame as the input argument and return a logical vector.

```
# Create the example data frame
df <- data.frame(user_id = c("t34", "t34", "t87", "t55", "t55", "t76", "t99"),
                 value = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Use the duplicate function
uniq_df <- df[!duplicated(df), ]
# Count number of value in uniq_df
table(uniq_df$value)

A B 
3 2
```